# Simple brightness but slow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image-processing, brightness

I have a picture, and I get every pixels and multiply the RGB for a number. I also need to take care when R * number > 255. When this happen, r = 255.
It's taking about 10s+ to complete a 1024x768 image. The common softwares that do brightness, takes less than 1s to do it. Any ideias to improve my strategy? Thanks.

Comment: Posting your code would be an extremely useful addition to this question.

Comment: I see you're doing this in C#. I can tell you that C# is *extremely* slow at image I/O because of the whole managed memory thing. There are ways to speed it up significantly, but it involves unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem:

[How to use ColorMatrix in .NET to change Brightness, Color, Saturation, Hue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888503/how-to-use-colormatrix-in-net-to-change-brightness-color-saturation-hue)

For brightness alone, colormatrix will work fine.  If you want to start using contrast, etc, you will need to use some other solution.  It seems to be SetPixel is the slowest part.  See this solution for doing this quickly:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/csharpgraphicfilters11.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Using a [ColorMatrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix.aspx) would probably be the best way to go. Here's an article to get you on your way: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Transformations0512192005050129AM/Transformations05.aspx

Answer (score 1):

when I did some simple image manipulation on multi megabyte images I significantly improved performance using unsafe code and pointer manipulation to get at the to the raw bytes.

This might get you in the right direction http://wcode.net/2009/08/unsafe-in-c-and-image-processing/

Answer (score 0):

well this site helped me a lot:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/03/08/bitmapsource-bitmap-interop.aspx